# Java - Composing String pathnames doesn't work

Tags: java, string, composition

When manipulating the pathnames of files and directories in `String` format, I use the convention that all directories pathnames ends with `File.separator`. This gives me an easy in-system way to differentiate between files and directories, and also allow me to compose pathnames very easily.

Java however doesn't follow this convention. This means that every time I acquire the pathname of a directory from somewhere, I need to check if it ends with `File.separator` and, if not, add the string to the pathname. Seems easy, right?

I can't manage to make it work.

The method `pathOfCurrentDirectory()` finds the directory of the program that starts the JVM and returns its absolute pathname *with `File.separator` at the end*. The method `createLogFile()` uses the previous method to create the absolute pathname of the log file, creates the missing directory if needed, creates the file, and then returns its absolute pathname.

The checks in `pathOfCurrentDirectory()` make it looks like its output truly ends with `File.separator` as intended. The checks in `createLogFile()` make it seem like it does not. What is happening?

```
    public static String createLogFile() {
        String pathOfCurrentDirectory = pathOfCurrentDirectory();
        String logDirectory = pathOfCurrentDirectory + "Log" + File.separator;
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("pathOfCurrentDirectory: " + pathOfCurrentDirectory
                    + "\n logDirectory = " + logDirectory);
        String path = logDirectory + "Log_" + LogUtilities.dateId() + ".log";
        System.out.println("logFile: " + path + "\n logFile.exists() = " + new File(path).exists());
        
        FilesUtility.createNewFile(new File(path));
        System.out.println("After creation, logFile.exists() = " + new File(path).exists());
        
        return path;
    }
    public static String pathOfCurrentDirectory() {
        String output = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")).getAbsolutePath();
    //  System.out.println("Dir: " + output);
    //  System.out.println("File.separatorChar = " + File.separatorChar);
        System.out.println("Last char of dir: " + output.charAt(output.length()-1));
        System.out.println("modifiedDir = " + (output + File.separator));
        String newOutput = (output + File.separator);
        System.out.println("newOutput = " + newOutput);
        //  return output;
        if( output.charAt(output.length()-1) == File.separatorChar )
             return newOutput;
        else return output; 
    }
```

Comment: It appears you have your `return` statements reversed in `pathOfCurrentDirectory`.  If `output` ends with a file separator character, don’t you want to return `output`?

Comment: Why not using Path objects for paths? Would be too slow to call `Files.isDirectory`? Also you would be able to use `Paths.get` to join paths.

Comment: Yes, please use `Paths`, that makes your whole code collapse into like 3 lines. Also, `System.getProperty("user.dir")` does _not_ return the current path, but the user home directory.

Comment: ...you are absolutely right, @VGR . Thank you

Comment: @daniu It’s the other way around.  user.dir is the current directory, user.home is the home directory.

Answer (score 2):

Java has 2 classes specifically for manipulating pathnames - File and Path, if you use these you will hardly ever need to use `File.separator` and risk String handling errors.

This shows using both File and Path:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    Files.createDirectories(Path.of(pathOfCurrentDirectory(), "Log"));
    File f = createLogAsFile();
    Path p = createLogAsPath();
}
private static Path createLogAsPath() throws IOException
{
    Path path = Path.of(pathOfCurrentDirectory(), "Log", "Log_" + LogUtilities.dateId() + ".log");
    System.out.println("createLogAsPath " + path + "\nFiles.isRegularFile(path) = " + Files.isRegularFile(path));
    Files.createFile(path);
    System.out.println("After creation, Files.isRegularFile(path) = " +Files.isRegularFile(path));
    return path;
}
private static File createLogAsFile() throws IOException
{
    File logDirectory = new File(pathOfCurrentDirectory(), "Log");
    File path = new File(logDirectory, "Log_" + LogUtilities.dateId() + ".log");
    System.out.println("createLogAsFile: " + path + "\n logFile.exists() = " + path.exists());
    path.createNewFile();
    System.out.println("After creation, logFile.exists() = " +path.exists());
    return path;
}
public static String pathOfCurrentDirectory() {
    return System.getProperty("user.dir");
}
```

Whether you use the File or Path version would depend on you other code thoug they are easy to switch between with toPath or toFile calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can really replace your `createLogFile()` with

```
String filename = String.format("Log_%s.log", LogUtilities.dateId());
Path logfile = Paths.get("Log", filename); 
FilesUtility.createNewFile(logfile.toFile());
```

Comment: If switching to `Path` is an option, why not also use `Files.createFile(logFile)`?

Comment: Why start with `"."`? It makes no difference.

Comment: @Andreas just in case he did want user dir, this makes explicit where to put it. Also, didn't really think that far ;) and hardly ever use this API.

Comment: @Slaw yeah but there might be additional stuff going on in his `FilesUtility.createNewFile()`. Not that I expect it to, so you're probably right.

Comment: Starting with `"."` will not make the file go in the *user dir*, it makes the file go in the *current dir* of the Java process, same as if you don't start with `"."`, i.e. `./Log/Log_20200721.log` and `Log/Log_20200721.log` is exactly the same.

Comment: @Andreas Im aware. It's just that in his question, his method is called `pathOfCurrentDirectory()` but returns `System.getProperty("user.dir")`, so it wasn't clear to me which one it was supposed to retrieve.

Comment: OK from the other comment I realized I was wrong about `user.dir`. Edited my answer.